# Deleting even a single relationship hang forever in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to delete a single relationship in a Neo4J database that contains over 200k ones, but it hangs forever. Here the request I am trying to execute:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:LINKED_TO]->() WITH r LIMIT 1 DELETE r
```

Is there an issue with the request, or any other reason why this is taking too much ? 
Is there another way to do it in a more optimal way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a label on one of the relationship's nodes, it will be much faster.

Without it, the database is doing a `all node scan`, and depending of size of your db, and where is the first node with a `LINKED_TO`, it can takes time ...

Comment: The nodes have a label "Type". You mean to add this in the request ?

Comment: Yes, ie do that : `MATCH p=(:Type)-[r:LINKED_TO]->() WITH r LIMIT 1 DELETE r`